# Localization with Storyboard - error when moving storyboards to Base folder

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to follow the tutorial posted on the Blog on how to localize with Storyboards

http://blog.xamarin.com/howto-localize-ios-storyboards-monotouch/

When I create the folder Base.lproj and move the storyboard, the app stops working and I get the following error when I run it:

MonoTouch.Foundation.MonoTouchException: Objective-C exception thrown. Name: NSInvalidArgumentException Reason: There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/Users/daniel/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/62404087-7F41-4A27-ADBD-4A0010BDD5C8/TestingApp.app/MainStoryboard_iPhone_Checklist.storyboardc' at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr) at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38 at TestingApp.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in /Users/daniel/Documents/github/TestingApp/TestingApp/iOS/TestingApp/TestingApp/Main.cs:17

(when the storyboard is on the root of the project, the project works fine)

Does anybody knows how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: This only works on iOS 6, were you trying this in the iOS 5 simulator?

Comment: @jonathanpeppers yes, I was trying with the iOS 6 simulator.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So here is my solution/workaround.

Instead of setting up the storyboard on the settings,  I get it on the AppDelagate like this:

```
UIStoryboard storyboard = UIStoryboard.FromName ("Base.lproj/MainStoryboard_iPhone_Checklist", null);
```

That way I dont get the exception and Localization works fine.

Comment: Do you put it in the constructor or as a private field?